# Cant get the value of req.userData.role

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The code right now is modifying a post as you can see with the router.put.

It checks `_id: req.params.id,`
`poster: req.userData.userId`
These two checks, allow the user who created the post to edit the post only.
But I'm trying to add an Admin that can modify any post. So I am trying to retrieve what role the user is but I can not seem to do that.

This is the code I'm running:

```
router.put("/:id",
  authCheck,
  multer({
    storage: storage
  }).single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
    let filePath = req.body.filePath;
    if (req.file) {
      const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
      filePath = url + '/documents/' + req.file.filename
    }
    const post = new Post({
      _id: req.body.id,
      header: req.body.header,
      message: req.body.message,
      filePath: filePath,
      poster: req.userData.userId,
    });
    console.log('user ROLE = ' ,req.userData.role);

    Post.updateOne({
      _id: req.params.id,
      poster: req.userData.userId
    }, post).then(result => {
      if (result.nModified > 0) {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Update successful!"
        });
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({
          message: "Not authorised!"
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

I'm not the most experienced coder, can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to obtain that value.

This is what I'm writing `console.log('user ROLE = ' ,req.userData.role);`

This is my user schema:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

This is my middleware if its needed:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'secret_this_is_my_secret');
    req.userData = { email: decodedToken.email, userId: decodedToken.userId, role: decodedToken.role };
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).son({message: 'Auth failed!' });
  }
}
```

If there is any other you would like to see let me know, thanks

Comment: What are you logging on that line? `undefined`? `TypeError`? Something else? Also, what happens if you log `decodedToken.role` in the middleware?

Comment: undefined in the log from that line.

Comment: Is it ever set in the first place? What happens if you log `decodedToken.role` in the middleware?

Comment: Cant seem to find the log, sorry as mentioned I am not the most experienced. Please give me a second, I will try get a result.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka `module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'secret_this_is_my_secret');
    req.userData = { email: decodedToken.email, userId: decodedToken.userId, role: decodedToken.role };
    console.log('logging decoded', decodedToken.role);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).son({message: 'Auth failed!' });
  }
}` but it is not logging in the terminal.

Comment: Are you sure the function you're exporting from that module is actually getting called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174444/discussion-between-andrew-and-charles-srstka).